# Send Gstreamer RTP packets using SIP

Tags: gstreamer, sip, rtp

I have an RTP audio stream provided by gstreamer and I want to send them using a SIP communication. Does anybody know how can I do it? Do I need a SIP proxy like OpenSIPS?

Comment: requests for library recommendations are off-topic here; I think your question would be much better if you instead described what you've tried so far, what you've researched about SIP and what specific problem you can't solve by looking at existing SIP clients.

Comment: @MarcusMüller What is the right place to ask?